# Color a column with VBA, if it has a space at the end

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of the (program) macro is to check the data in the table columns to see if they are in the correct format. If they are not in the correct format, the line is marked in red (background color) and the writing of the badly formatted box (or boxes) is blank. So how can I color if the format ( the format that i want to check if there are spaces useless )is not good?
can someone konw how

```
Sub deletespace()
'deleteespace_description Macro
    Dim cell As Range
    Range("E:V").Select
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the format you want to check?

Comment: Alex Martinez,  the  format  that i want to check if there are spaces useless

Comment: The trim function is going to remove leading and trailing spaces.  So you won't be checking for those any longer.  Do you mean too many spaces between strings in the case of a multiple word string or do you mean if the cell is empty.  You want to format before you delete those spaces?  I am not sure anyone knows what to do with this.

Comment: Wookies-Will-Code I want to delete the spaces before and afther description not between words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want to check only the cells in the Range("E:V"), which are within the `UsedRange` judging from your code:

```
Sub DeleteSpaces()

    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim checkIntersect  As Range
    Dim ws              As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set checkIntersect = ws.Range("E:V")

    With WorksheetFunction
        For Each myCell In Intersect(ws.UsedRange, checkIntersect)
            If Len(.Trim(myCell)) <> Len(myCell) Then myCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

The idea is to compare `Len(.Trim(myCell))` with `Len(myCell)`, and if it is different to color the interior in `vbRed`. `myCell` is used as a variable, just for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @DisplayName - yup, otherwise the `With-End with` was quite useless, but it was working well w/o them :)

Comment: you know the difference: `Worksheetfunction.Trim()` detects inner spaces also while VBA `Trim()` doesn't. So if OP's interested in detecting inner _useless_ spaces, then that "dot" is mandatory

Comment: BTW I'd move `With ... End With` outside the `For Each` loop

Comment: @DisplayName - inner useless spaces? Can you give an example, I am somehow missing your point?

Comment: In _Immediate Window_ `?len("| 1  2 |"),len(worksheetfunction.trim("| 1  2 |")), len(trim("| 1  2 |"))` would output ` 8             7             8 `

Comment: @DisplayName - great example,I suppose that you are away from keyboard now & chatting from your phone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165982/discussion-between-displayname-and-vityata).

Comment: nothing happens with this code Vityata, I want to check if my columns are in good format (the good format that there are spaces neither before nor after not between words) if it is not the right format the bottom becomes red and the white writing

Comment: sorry i want  just none at the start/end (VBA TRIM) and only singles (Worksheet TRIM) elsewhere? @pnuts

Comment: i want just colour  the 'rogues' can you help me please @pnuts